# SNI and SSL on IIS 8.5

Tags: ssl, iis, paypal, sni

I have a website running on IIS that requires two SSL certificates, one for the main website domain, and one for the traffic coming through a CDN (the assets are served from a different domain name). Both use SSL.

I therefore used the Server Name Indication option when creating the HTTPS bindings in IIS.

The site works fine, I know that users on IE6/Windows XP may experience an issue, but we don't have any/many users visiting our site using that combination so that's not a problem. However, it is an ecommerce site that receives postbacks/callbacks from both PayPal and WorldPay. Here is where we are experiencing an issue. It would seem that neither PayPal or WorldPay's mechanism for posting back payment information understands SNI, therefore we don't get notified that a payment has been made.

I'm not sure what the options are. IIS is telling me to create a default SSL site, but I can't find any instructions online regarding what I should be creating, or what benefit it serves.

Am I going down the right path with this? Can anyone offer any advice on a) whether a default SSL site will fix this issue and b) how to create the default SSL site?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Kind regards,
Dotdev

Comment: You should use a tool such as Wireshark to better understand what exactly leads to the failures of PayPal. By analyzing the SSL/TLS handshakes, the cause can be found and then conclusion on how to fix might arise. The workaround though, is to create a catch all default web site and give it a traditional IP based SSL binding (not SNI), so that it can handle non-SNI compliant clients.

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for your comment. I'll look into Wireshark. The default website, would it be pointing to same home directory as the website, but this time just with the SSL binding on the IP address for HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have all your sites configured to require SNI.

From what you're saying, your callbacks from PayPal and WorldPay are on your main site are they?

If this is the case, you can simply edit the binding on your main site so that it does not require SNI, and make sure it is set to "All unassigned" rather than a specific IP address (otherwise it will get in the way of the SNI site).